# How to add different calculations for two text fields, multiple labels and one button

Tags: c#, xcode

I'm using text fields, for the user to input data, and labels to show the data once it has been calculated. 
When I times the two text fields together, it works perfectly. However when I introduce more labels (I need the two text fields to be involved with different formulas to produce 13 different labels), it interferes with the initial two and the maths doesn't work.

This snippet of code works:

```
float floatHeightResult=[rectWidth.text floatValue] *
[rectLength.text floatValue];

NSString *stringHeightResult=[[NSString alloc]
                            initWithFormat:@"%1.2f",floatHeightResult];

heightResult.text=stringHeightResult;
```

But as soon as i introduce other additions such as the following, it doesn't work:

```
float floatWeightResult=[rectWidth.text floatValue] +
[rectWidth.text floatValue] * 2.87 ;

NSString *stringWeightResult=[[NSString alloc]
                             initWithFormat:@"%1.2f",floatWeightResult];

widthResult.text=stringWeightResult;
```

How can I add the two numbers together, and then times that result by another number?

Answer (score 0):

//i think it ll be helpfull for you..

```
float fl_rectWidth = [rectWidth.text floatValue];
float fl_rectLength = [rectLength.text floatValue];

float floatHeightResult = fl_rectWidth * fl_rectLength;

lbl_heightResult.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.2f",floatHeightResult];

float floatWeightResult = fl_rectWidth + floatHeightResult ;

lbl_widthResult.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.2f",floatWeightResult];
```